# Python Standard Deviation - Efficiency issues with assigning variables

Tags: python, math

I'm currently working on a program to find standard deviation, z score, etc from some numbers, but my program is extremely inefficient. The way I'm doing it right now by assigning each number its own variable, adding, dividing, assigning that a new variable, so it becomes an infinitely large wall of code. What would be a more efficient way of calculating this than assigning each number its own variable? Also, is there a way to make a list of these numbers based on the number of numbers the user inputs and append these numbers to the list AND THEN do the math?

Comment: You might be doing something so weird that it's hard to imagine. Please, post some of the code.

Comment: This guy underneath me already answered it :)

Comment: Yes, you can put numbers in a list.  In general, they should be in some 'iterable'.  In Python3.5, a new statistics module was added to the stdlib to enable proper calculation of simple statistics without installing numpy and scipy or other fancy stats package.

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed, use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).
With just using the numpy array things are going to go MUCH faster.

Also scipy has what you want, see [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)